# large spacing between listview

Tags: java, android, sql, sql-server, listview

This is listview java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager_dashboard);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    itemsArrayList = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>();
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            String text = search.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            myAppAdapter.filter(text);
        }
    });

    SyncData orderData = new SyncData();
    orderData.execute("");

    shp = this.getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);

    String userid = shp.getString("UserId", "none");

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    TextView textViewUserId = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.textViewUserId);
    textViewUserId.setText(userid);
}
private class SyncData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String msg = "Error";
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(ManagerDashboard.this, "Synchronising",
                "Listview Loading! Please Wait...", true);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {
            Connection conn = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (conn == null) {
                success = false;
            } else {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Dashboard";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                if (rs != null) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        try {
                            if (rs.getString("AccountType").equals("Seller")) {
                                itemsArrayList.add(new ClassListItems(rs.getString("slsperid"), rs.getString("Visibility_Tgt"),
                                        rs.getString("Visibility_Actual"), rs.getString("GPTgt"),
                                        rs.getString("GPAct"), rs.getString("GSTgt"), rs.getString("GSAct")));
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    msg = "Found";
                    success = true;
                } else {
                    msg = "No Data found!";
                    success = false;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Writer writer = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            msg = writer.toString();
            success = false;
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        progress.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(ManagerDashboard.this, msg + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if (success == false) {
        } else {
            try {
                myAppAdapter = new MyAppAdapter(itemsArrayList, ManagerDashboard.this);
                listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                listView.setAdapter(myAppAdapter);
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Listview adapter

```
public class MyAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvuserid, tvvstarget, tvvsact, tvvsp, tvgptarget, tvgpact, tvgpp, tvgstarget, tvgsact, tvgsp;
    }

    public List<ClassListItems> parkingList;

    public Context context;
    ArrayList<ClassListItems> arrayList;

    private MyAppAdapter(List<ClassListItems> apps, Context context){
        this.parkingList = apps;
        this.context = context;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<ClassListItems>();
        arrayList.addAll(parkingList);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {return parkingList.size();}

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {return position;}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {return position;}

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(rowView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_content, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvuserid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvuserid);
            viewHolder.tvvstarget = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvvstarget);
            viewHolder.tvvsact = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvvsact);
            viewHolder.tvvsp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvvsp);
            viewHolder.tvgptarget = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgptarget);
            viewHolder.tvgpact = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgpact);
            viewHolder.tvgpp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgpp);
            viewHolder.tvgstarget = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgstarget);
            viewHolder.tvgsact = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgsact);
            viewHolder.tvgsp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvgsp);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.tvuserid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName()+"");
        viewHolder.tvvstarget.setText(parkingList.get(position).getVisibility_Tgt()+"");
        viewHolder.tvvsact.setText(parkingList.get(position).getVisibility_Actual()+"");
        viewHolder.tvuserid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName()+"");
        viewHolder.tvgptarget.setText(parkingList.get(position).getGPTgt()+"");
        viewHolder.tvgpact.setText(parkingList.get(position).getGPAct()+"");
        viewHolder.tvuserid.setText(parkingList.get(position).getName()+"");
        viewHolder.tvgstarget.setText(parkingList.get(position).getGSTgt()+"");
        viewHolder.tvgsact.setText(parkingList.get(position).getGSAct()+"");

        Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvvstarget.getText().toString());
        Double value2 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvvsact.getText().toString());
        Double calculatedValue = (value2*100)/value1;
        String formattedValue = String.format("%.2f", calculatedValue);
        viewHolder.tvvsp.setText(formattedValue.toString()+"%");

        Double value3 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvgptarget.getText().toString());
        Double value4 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvgpact.getText().toString());
        Double calculatedValue2 = (value4*100)/value3;
        String formattedValue2 = String.format("%.2f", calculatedValue2);
        viewHolder.tvgpp.setText(formattedValue2.toString()+"%");

        Double value5 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvgstarget.getText().toString());
        Double value6 = Double.parseDouble(viewHolder.tvgsact.getText().toString());
        Double calculatedValue3 = (value6*100)/value5;
        String formattedValue3 = String.format("%.2f", calculatedValue3);
        viewHolder.tvgsp.setText(formattedValue3.toString()+"%");

        return rowView;
    }

    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        parkingList.clear();
        if(charText.length() == 0){
            parkingList.addAll(arrayList);
        } else {
            for (ClassListItems apps: arrayList){
                if (apps.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){
                    parkingList.add(apps);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ManagerDashboard.this,
                ManagerActivity.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ManagerDashboard.this,
                ManagerProfile.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dashboard) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        LogOut();
        return true;

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

public void LogOut() {
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = shp.edit();
    edit.putString("UserId", "");
    edit.commit();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ManagerDashboard.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
}
```

This is activity xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Seller"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.23"
        android:text="VS %"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:text="GP %"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.18"
        android:text="GS %"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/search"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"/>
```

This is listview xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvuserid"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:text="Seller"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvvsp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:text="VS %"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvgpp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="GP %"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvgsp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="GS %"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvvstarget"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvvsact"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvgptarget"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvgpact"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvgstarget"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvgsact"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Why the listview got extra space? Even i chg the padding in xml file it wont change. It happen when i add much id in viewholder. That means if in viewholder only gt 4 id the listview did not have extra space in the bottom of every item. How to do the spacing divided equally? Anyone help pls. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change height of listView to wrap_content.

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_marginTop="210dp"/>
```